# How to use almond with amd-optimise for gulp?

Tags: requirejs, gulp, almond

In order to minimise the footprint of my single page webapp I want to replace ReqireJS with [almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) but even after reading the docs and googling I still have no idea how to plug the almond into my gulp build.

Let's say I have a script like this:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var amdOptimize = require("amd-optimize");
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task("scripts:index", function () {

    return gulp.src("js/**/*.js")
        // Traces all modules and outputs them in the correct order.
        .pipe(amdOptimize("main"))
        .pipe(concat("index.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/scripts"));

});
```

Where does the almond goes to?

Bonus question: How do I make the build script modify the dist version of my index.html to replace the  require.js reference with a reference to almond automatically?